# Renormalizing Chaos: Transition in a Logistic Map

Tags: renormalization, chaos-theory

I am currently trying to understand the analysis of a [logistic-like map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Chaos_and_the_logistic_map) $$f_\mu (x) = 1-\mu x^2$$

after section 2.2 in "[Renormalization Methods](http://books.google.com/books/about/Renormalization_methods.html?id=Wc11QgAACAAJ)" by A. Lesne.

As I understand it, the physical situation is that $f_\mu$ has exactly $2^n$ attractors $x_{i\dots 2^n}$ in a certain region $\mu\in [0,\mu_c)$. Since one can order them such that $f_\mu(x_i) = x_{i+1}$ and the number of attractors grows in some way always by a factor of two, it is called "double-periodic scenario".

However, at $\mu_c\approx1.401$, this behavior cannot be found any more and one might interprete this as [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28thermodynamics%29) since the system appears to be **chaotic** from there, or, in some sense, the number of iterations it takes until a point $x$ is reached again becomes infinity.

Here is a scetch of the situation:
[image: Logistic-Like-Map]

At certain points $\mu_i$, $i=[i,\infty]$, the number of attractors doubles until $\mu_c$ is reached where this periodicity cannot be found. $N$ has been chosen to be sufficiently large.

To understand the transition from the periodic point of view, Lesne conjectures that some delta exists such that $$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\delta^i (\mu_c - \mu_i)=A\neq0\ .$$
Then, it is stated that $\delta \approx 4.67$ is somehow universal and can be derived using a **renormalization** approach of the form $R\left[ f\right] \propto f^k$ with $R$ beeing an operator that contains in the end all the informations about the system.

Two things are unclear to me:

> #### How can one use the renormalization operator $R$ to analyze the critical behaviour, thus $\delta$?

and

> #### Is there a systematic way to find an appropriate $R$ better than just looking at self-similarities of some graphs?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The [book by Sethna](http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/sethna/StatMech/) has a very good exercise on understanding the logistic map with renormalisation; it walks you through the steps but leaves the calculations up to you. Using renormalisation in practise needs practice, so I think the best way forward here is to actually do it.

Comment: Link to the exercise: http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/sethna/StatMech/ComputerExercises/PeriodDoubling/PeriodDoubling.html

Comment: @genneth: Thank you for the link, this seems to be exactly what I need. As you say, understanding renormalization needs practice and this is what I need :) If you want, you can kind of sum up the main points of the exercise as an answer and I would be glad to accept it. Greets

Comment: I think you should take Ron's answer --- it's correct and concise, and contains a great reference.

Comment: @genneth: So shall it be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best reference for this is Feigenbaum's original article, reprinted in "Universality in Chaos" by Cvitanovic. The point is that when you iterate a map, every time you period double, you fold up the function one more time. The behavior is dominated by the solution to the following equation:

$$ \alpha g(g(x/\alpha)) = g(x)$$

Which says that g iterated with itself and rescaled (both in the domain and range) looks just like g. The function $g$ is shifted relative to f, so that it's maximum is at 0, not at some point between 0 and 1, which means you don't have to follow the critical point under iteration. You can solve this condition more easily by imposing the symmetry $g(x)=g(-x)$ and using a Taylor expansion, and this gives g and $\alpha$, and $\alpha$ is the scale exponent. Everything about the critical behavior is determined by g, and this is described best in the original article.

Comment: Good answer, though I think you should make it clear that your $g$ is a shifted version of the $f$ used by the questioner, such that the hump is centred at $x=0$. Also, I'm not sure the condition $g(x) = g(-x)$ is necessary --- I was under the impression that as long as you shift the window appropriately it will renormalise to the same universal function anyway.

Comment: @genneth: the condition is not necessary, but it halves the work of solving the equation, so it is useful.

Comment: @Ron: Thank you for your nice answer, I am sure that it is conceptually right. However, I will not accept it right now since someone might come up with something more detailed. Greets